# Isolated network within a network

Tags: networking, router

I'm in a student flat, and every one of the ~90 rooms is sharing a single /24 subnet. I'd quite like to create my own independent network that I can run all of my PCs and such without everyone else's stuff interfering with mine, and without them being able to get at my stuff. I'm a little lost as to the best device to do this however.

What would do it? Do I need a special kind of router, or would a normal router do the job?

Thanks, 
Mini

Comment: Can you clarify if you need your network of PCs to be able to access outside resources? For example, you don't anyone seeing your stuff, but you want to be able to get to Google.

Answer (score 2):

Any usual SOHO router can do this job, but it needs to be properly configured (DHCP, NAT, subnets to only name a few points). You should also ask for permission first, as most network admins aren't too fond of users hooking up their own active components...

Answer (score 0):

If your entire network is physically united, then you can just invent any subnet and use it's addresses.  You just need to avoid conflicts. Your computers will talk between each other independently. You can make one of your computers multihomed and turn on routing on it.

This won't work if your net uses sophisticated switches.

P.S. You don't need router to work in one subnet.

Comment: I don't want to down vote the answer, because your answer is *technically* correct. However, you have not really provided an answer to the question. You mentioned have a multihomed computers, but did not mention what specific configuration is required. Also, if you are going to mention "sophisticated switches" you should explain what that means.